# Why does order by clause doesn't work as expected when using with joins and inner query

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

Below is the query i tried running, it gives the correct output except that its order by is not working? I would like to order by fiscal_week first and then by region. Can any one help me out?

```
select 'CPD' as LOB,b.region, [FISC_WEEK_VAL], count(distinct a.qte_num_val) CPD_Qte_cnt into CPD_Qte_cnt_CQ_tog
from
(   
    select a.[SUB_ACCT_ID], a.qte_num_val, SnP_LOB_Lvl_1, SnP_LOB_Lvl_3, SnP_LOB_Lvl_6, [FISC_WEEK_VAL],[Converted_Flag]
    ,row_number() over (partition by a.[SUB_ACCT_ID], SnP_LOB_Lvl_6 order by [QUOTE_CREATE_DATE] desc, qte_num_val desc) as rownbr
    from EAP_Global..[tbl_Quotes_Snp_AMER] a
    where [FISC_QTR_VAL] = '2020-Q1' and  [FISC_WEEK_VAL] <'2020-W05' and country='US'  and SnP_LOB_Lvl_1 in ('Client Peripherals','Displays') and a.[SUB_ACCT_ID] is not null
    and LOB_DESC in ('CLIENT PERIPHERALS','Displays','Precision Desktops','Latitude','Precision Notebooks','OptiPlex Desktops')
    group by a.[SUB_ACCT_ID], a.qte_num_val, SnP_LOB_Lvl_1, SnP_LOB_Lvl_3, SnP_LOB_Lvl_6,[QUOTE_CREATE_DATE],[FISC_WEEK_VAL],[Converted_Flag]
)a 
inner join EAP_EUC_NA..MD_SR_info_direct_indirect b on a.[SUB_ACCT_ID]=b.account_id 
where region is not NULL and rownbr=1
group by b.region, [FISC_WEEK_VAL]
order by 3,2
```

Comment: You are using a select into, which means no data is returned, it is inserted in a new table. How do you figure the order by doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Adding to the comment by @HoneyBadger, a table is logically an unorder set of rows so you need to specify the `ORDER BY` when selecting from the table, not loading it.

Comment: I would recommend not using ordinal position in an order by. If you change your columns the order may be incorrect unless you also change the order by.

Comment: Thank you for your response. After research got to figure out that on selecting data from table order by can be used whereas inserting into a table doesn't guarantee ordered set of rows.